# Android - smsManager.sendTextMessage

Tags: android, sms

In this following code message is a Message class array which contains 100+ phonenumbers and sms messages.

```
for(Message msg: message)  {
    String msgString = msg.getSMSText1() + " " + msg.getTransporterNo() + "\n" + msg.getSMSText2();
    smsManager.sendTextMessage(msg.getPhoneNo(), null, msgString, piSent, null);
}
```

And this code for receiving broadcast after sending a message:

```
PendingIntent piSent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(this, 0, new Intent("SMS_SENT"), PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);
BroadcastReceiver smsSentReceiver = new BroadcastReceiver() {
    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
        String result = "";
        switch(getResultCode()) {
            case Activity.RESULT_OK:
                result = "Transmission successful";
                break;
            case SmsManager.RESULT_ERROR_GENERIC_FAILURE:
                result = "Transmission failed";
                break;
            case SmsManager.RESULT_ERROR_RADIO_OFF:
                result = "Radio off";
                break;
            case SmsManager.RESULT_ERROR_NULL_PDU:
                result = "No PDU defined";
                break;
            case SmsManager.RESULT_ERROR_NO_SERVICE:
                result = "No service";
                break;
        }
        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), result,
                Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }
};
registerReceiver(smsSentReceiver, new IntentFilter("SMS_SENT"));
```

Is there a way to pass additional data during smsManager.sendTextMessage? I'd like to pass additional data like message_id, and phonenumber so that I can find out which message was success or not.

Answer (score 0):

You can attach the necessary data as extras on the `Intent` object. For example:

```
Intent sentIntent = new Intent("SMS_SENT");
sentIntent.putExtra("message_id", id);
sentIntent.putExtra("phone_number", number);
PendingIntent piSent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(this, 0, sentIntent, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);
```

Then you can retrieve them from the `Intent` passed into the `onReceive()` method of your `BroadcastReceiver`:

```
int id = intent.getIntExtra("message_id", -1);
String number = intent.getStringExtra("phone_number");
```

Also, as David Wasser reminded me below, to ensure a new `PendingIntent` is issued each time through the loop, you'll need to provide each a unique request code - the second argument in the `getBroadcast()` call. If the message IDs are unique, you can use those. Otherwise, a loop counter should suffice.

Comment: This will only work if the device only sends one SMS and then waits for the SENT and DELIVERY callbacks before sending the next one. Otherwise the EXTRAS will be overwritten. Since the code is sending these messages in a loop, this will not work. All calls to `getIntExtra()` will return the last sent `message_id`

Comment: @DavidWasser Oops, good point. I neglected to add a unique request code. Thanks.

Comment: Sorry, I know this is old thread. But do you know how to solve my problem. My app successfuly receives delivery reports, but if i send in loop 1000+ messages my app mixs intent extras after 256 undelivered messages. I have unique request_code for each PendingIntent.

Comment: @Ivan Sorry, no. I saw your question when you posted it, but I didn't really have any suggestions for you, as I've never seen or heard of such behavior.

Comment: @MikeM. One more question. Do you know is it possible to catch delivery report without pending intent? So just like receiving standard SMS, can i define receiver in manifest file which will give me raw delivery message PDU where i can extract gsm number of user which received message. In this case i dont need to know any more extra data, only gsm number if user who received my message. This wouls sove all m problems :)

Comment: @Ivan Hmm, I really don't think so, not for regular apps, anyway. However, I don't think I've ever dug through the source to investigate that particular mechanism, so I'm not 100% certain. I assume that, though delivery reports are basically regular messages, the system will direct it only through those passed `PendingIntent`s, if they're present. Otherwise, I'm guessing it gets dropped. I might have a deeper look later on, and I'll let you know if I find anything useful, but don't get your hopes up. :-)

Comment: @Mike M. Thank you very very much for your help ;)